# RDLC reports are not working after deployed to IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, reportviewer, rdlc

after publishing mvc web application to IIS 7.0, the problem was that the reports are not working, however, i did the following but it didn't worked :

1. Installed MICROSOFT® REPORT VIEWER 2012 RUNTIME package from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747
   After installation, found Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll in 
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer
2. go to IIS Manager --> choose the Web Application which contains the reports, and then choose Handler Mappings
3. in Handler Mappings, Add a new Handler, Set its info as the following:

   Request Path : Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd

   Type: Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms

   Name: Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd
4. Found the below handler got added automatically in web.config under
    system webserver section in

   `<handlers>
         <add name="Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>`

I'm using Visual studio 2013, dot net framework 4.5

Please guide me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain was "not working" means... What happend? Error messages should be included in the question...

Comment: Its not showing anything. its showing blank screen in http://localhost/Latest/Reports/GenerateAndDisplayReport?format=PDF. Where as it is showing report(pdf) in my local machine

Comment: Anything in the logs? can it reach the database from where it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a view in Oracle DB to produce the report. That view is not working properly. We just dropped and re-created the view and it is working fine. Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: which `View` is not working properly. I'm facing same issue. I know its been over a year but please help  if you can.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure all the files related to RDLC are there in the published files.
If it is not there copy and paste it from Project file

Answer (score 3):

- Copy `.rdlc` folder to `bin` folder in the project directory.
- Deploy your project to the server again.

Hope it'll solve your issue.

Best-